# JS: Animate div after changing it's display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs, onCLick function will set 1st `display: none;` 2nd `display: block;` AND I want to animate rotation of 2nd div after it'll replace 1st. Sadly animation not working, it only does that function.

HTML:

```
 <div class="more-click">           
    <img src="img/arrow-more.png">  
 </div>
 <div class="more-click-back">
    <img src="img/arrow-more.png">
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.more-click{
 display: block;
 transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.more-click-back{
 display: none;
 transition-duration: .5s;
 transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

JS:

```
 $(".more-click img").click(function () {
        $(".more-click").css('display', 'none');
        $(".more-click-back").css('display', 'block');
        $(".more-click-back").css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
 });
```

Does anyone know, why my 0.5s animation isn't working? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change this :

```
 $(".more-click-back").css('display', 'block');
```

and make it fade in so the animation will work fine like this :

```
$(".more-click-back").fadeIn(300)
```

I made this edit on your code and you can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/swuogr4y/

Comment: OK, I'm sorry, just noticed. It's really working only one-way.